# Cannot Invoke an Object which is possible undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript with react, and I get this error.

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
const onChange: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined
```

Here is my code where I get the errors.

```
interface FilterGroupsProps {
  data?: any[];
  selectedGroups?: any[];
  onChange?: (...args: any[]) => any;
}

// Inside the class
  onClick = (groupName: string) => (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    event.preventDefault();
    onChange(groupName);
  };

//Inside the render:
          {allUniqueGroups.map((group: string) => (
            <a
              key={group}
              className="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              href="#"
              onClick={this.onClick(group)}
            >
```

What I do not understand with this error is the following: The groupName should be available when this onClick is rendered.

Which means I am kind of confused where my security case should be handled. Can you explain the problem here? As well as provide me with a solution to this problem.

Comment: You've made `onChange` optional in the interface - so it "is possibly 'undefined'". This should fix it:  `<any> onChange(groupName)`

Comment: Yeah, you need to check it first... e.g., `if (onChange) { onChange(groupName); }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at `FilterGroupsProps`:

```
interface FilterGroupsProps {
  data?: any[];
  selectedGroups?: any[];
  onChange?: (...args: any[]) => any;
}
```

`onChange` is possibly `undefined` or `provided`.

Here is my approach:

```
onClick = (groupName: string) => (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  if (this.props.onChange) {
   const { onChange } = this.props;
   event.preventDefault();
   onChange(groupName);
  }
  // or do something else...
};
```

Or solution from comments by **Randy** to remove `optional` *flag* from `onChange` method:

```
interface FilterGroupsProps {
  data?: any[];
  selectedGroups?: any[];
  onChange: (...args: any[]) => any;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your solution. Think is I do not think I need the security Check here. As Randy Casburn mentioned above, I need to remove the optional flag from the interface.
Please add that as the appropriate answer, and your current solution as an alternative and I will accept your answer. Thank you..

Comment: Thanks for your response, it helped me. The only thing I would change is to reverse the `if` condition, to avoid nesting.

Comment: The last part of this answer worked for me: removing the _optional_ flag (or in my case it is a `tsx` file that's using `InferProps` for PropTypes; so for me it was a matter of adding `isRequired` to the erroring function props in question.